# Bind Selectric jQuery Dropdown excluding option selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using selectric jQuery dropdown in my webdesign:

```
<select id="RemoveReason">
    <option value="0">Reason for Disconnect</option>
    <option>Coverage</option>
    <option>Price</option>
    <option>Customer experience</option>
    <option>Serviceability</option>
    <option>Promotion</option>
    <option>Limited Device range</option>
</select>
```

With this I am getting the value at 0 position again in the select dropdown upon default select. [You can find an image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdwwX.png)

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: show us your js-code

Comment: $('select').selectric({
      disableOnMobile:false,
      maxHeight: 220
     });
                                                                          $('select').livequery(function(){
      $('select').selectric({
       disableOnMobile:false,
       maxHeight: 220
      });
     });

Answer (score 0):

Add `selected` and `disabled` , I believe this is what you expected.

```
 <select id="RemoveReason">
  <option value="0" selected disabled>Reason for Disconnect</option>
  <option>Coverage</option>
  <option>Price</option>
  <option>Customer experience</option>
  <option>Serviceability</option>
  <option>Promotion</option>
  <option>Limited Device range</option></select>
```

Comment: it only hides the option,but i dont want to display it in dropdown. is there any way?

Comment: No you can't ,  what you can do is to remove the "Reason for Disconnect" and put it out of the <select>,  like this:
<p>Reason for Disconnect</p> 
<select id="RemoveReason">
      <option>Coverage</option>
      <option>Price</option>
      <option>Customer experience</option>
      <option>Serviceability</option>
      <option>Promotion</option>
      <option>Limited Device range</option></select>